# Which Raban Gamliel was in the first mishnah of masechet berakhot?

Tags: history, rabbis, mishna, tractate-brachot, tannaim

Who was this Raban Gamliel in the first mishnah of masechet berakhot?
Raban Gamliel I?
Raban Gamliel II?
Raban Gamliel III?
Are there some books who could help me to find the historic part of the Mishnah? like dates and things like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can found in Sefer Seder Hadorot, [Tanayim VeAmorayim](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=46819#) that it was Raban Gamliel DeYavne, the second Raban Gamliel: I will copy here one statement from the book:

> רבן גמליאל דיבנה בן ר"ש הנהרג בן ר"ג הזקן. א) במשנה ברכות פ"א ב'. פ"ב ה', פו ח', ... ‏

See [here](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01825.html?dyn#tanaiim) in Seder Hadorot Hamekutsar, line 12.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, because in the same mishnah  rabbi Eliezer HaGadol appears , and he is a contemporary of Raban Gamliel DeYavne. 
Thank you for the link and for the response.